How should I validate objects with cross-service reference fields in a Microservices Architecture?
I'm currently working on a project with Microservices Architecture (MSA), but there are product services and order services, and I'm going to save the product code in the order service. In the existing monolith, we verified whether the product code actually exists or Else, but the product object is not in the order service when it comes to MSA, so I'd like to hear your opinion on what to do in this case by communicating between servers such as RestTemplate
I haven't tried anything yet. I don't know what to do

please, at very least, complete the [tour]

What I would do would depend on the functional and non-functional requirements, but in the absence of any other firm steer, I would start by porting your validation to the microservices architecture (option 2 below.)

If it didn't matter that much whether the product actually existed (perhaps because it would be validated at a later point in the business process) I might consider not validating it in the Order service.
If it did matter whether the product actually existed and I could tolerate the extra latency and the cost of the extra network call, I would make a REST call out to the Product service to check the existence of the product. I recommend you start with this option and work out if it causes problems before considering other options.
If it did matter whether the product actually existed and I felt that I could not tolerate the extra latency or the cost of the network call, but I could afford extra memory storage at the Order service, I would maintain a local cache of products in the Order service, perhaps using a distributed caching technology such as Hazelcast. Or, seeing as your question is tagged with Java and Spring, you could cache the results of calls made to the Product service using Spring Cache, essentially 'memoizing' the results of calls made to the Product service transparently.  Note that caching comes with further complications. If products could be deleted or become otherwise unavailable and you had a cache of products within the Order service you would need to proactively remove those orders from the Order service's product cache, in which case you would end up publishing events describing product deletion to a 'topic', which your Order service would then 'subscribe' to (this could happen either by using something like JMS or a web hook) and remove products from the cache when it received an event.

